# skip required validation on tab out

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a cascading LOV, with Department and Class. After I select a Department ID (inputComboBoxLOV), I will populate the department Name. 
Now my Class values are filtered and if I select a Class, Class name is populated.

But now if I go to Department field and delete the value and tab out, required validation is firing. Instead i want the valueChangeListener to be called so that I can set my attribute value to null and hence populate department name with null.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

I have tried to remove, required tag on Department field, it seems to work perfect, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the required property of the UI component and make sure it doesn't do auto submit too.

Comment: As per my logic, I need the required tag as well as autoSubmit property. As this is a cascading LOV, and I want to filter Class LOV based on the selection of Department LOV

Comment: Required means not null - so your requirement and your flow of operations doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you'll remove the required property on the field and keep the auto submit this will invoke the validation listener - in it you can write any logic you want. Otherwise the required property (implemented as JS on the client) is checked before the value change listener.

Comment: yes, required means not null, but for time being I want it to accept null values so that I can populate the cascading fields below it to null. Then while navigating away from the page, I want the required validation to be thrown.  P.S: Unfortunately, my OK button has `skipValidation to true` so I will not be able to write condition there to validate these fields while navigating away.

Answer (score -1):

To skip validation you can make immediate property true.

Comment: i do not think its true, please see this blog http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html